# Is there a name for a directed graph where we cannot re-enter a vertex that we leave (to a different vertex)?

Tags: dynamic-programming, directed-graphs

I am wondering if there is an "official" name for a *directed* graph where we cannot re-enter a vertex once we leave it to a *different* vertex. Here's an example of one such graph, where once you leave a given vertex to a different one, there is no way to come back to the same vertex.

[image: graph example]

I encounter these type of graphs frequently in dynamic programming problems where we progress from state -> state in stages, where, in certain classes of problems, we won't be able to go back to a state already visited (once you left it for a different one). Hence, my interest in these kinds of graphs.

Here's an example graph of a matrix multiply optimization problem (i.e., find the optimal sequence of matrix multiplications to minimize the total number of elementary operations), that shows this property (A, B, C, D are matrices).

[image: matrix multiply optimization]

Is there a special name for such graphs, or should I invent one? Is there also an efficient algorithm to detect such types of graphs?

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: (I guess a loop makes a graph cyclic. There is [Mathematics@SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: If you don't like the solution by Andrej, maybe a *forward* graph.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes. It is certainly not a DAG since it has a loop, but it cannot go backwards, so yes, direct "forward" graph sounds a little better. Either way, it seem like there is no special name for such graphs already. The special thing about these graphs is that it makes for simpler backtracking (in DP). You'll just need to remember the previous vertex (or "state") from which you arrived in a given vertex for each of the vertices.

Comment: Mh, this is true of a general graph, isn't it ?

Comment: Here's a graph where you can go backwards: { A -> B -> C -> D -> B; D -> E -> F }. You can go still backwards to B once you leave it to C (via  C -> D -> B). In the first example I posted, you cannot go backwards to B once you leave it to C or D.